# Why does GCC 6 assume data is 16-byte aligned?

Tags: c++, gcc, glibc, memory-alignment, gcc6

*(Sorry in advance for not having managed to reduce my problem to a simple failing test case...)*

I have faced issues with upgrading to GCC 6.3.0 to build our codebase (relevant flags: `-O3 -m32`).

Specifically, my application segfaults within a struct ctor call because of GCC optimizations.

In this ctor, GCC used `movaps` :

```
movaps %xmm0,0x30a0(%ebx)
```

`movaps` *requires* the operand to be **16-byte aligned**. But at this point in time, `%ebx` points to my object, which is **not necessarily 16-byte aligned**. From glibc :

> “The address of a block returned by malloc or realloc in GNU systems is always a multiple of eight (or sixteen on 64-bit systems).“

Hence the segfault (when built with `-O3 -m32`).

**Why does it seem like GCC assumed the allocated object would be 16-byte aligned ? Am I misunderstanding something ?**

Notes:

- No alignment hints or attributes on this struct
- Object has been initialized via default `new` operator
- Depends on the level of optimization:

  - PASS: `-m32 -O2`
  - FAIL: `-m32 -O2 -ftree-slp-vectorize`
  - PASS: `-m32 -O3 -fno-tree-slp-vectorize`
  - FAIL: `-m32 -O3`

---

This other project, seem to have hit similar issues : https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/4623

Their investigation points to `-fvect-cost-model=dynamic`. Investigation on my codebase rather points to `-ftree-slp-vectorize`.

Comment: Using `alignof` on your object would tell you what alignment the compiler thinks it needs.  Sounds like it should not be ≥16, but would hurt to check.

Comment: It wouldn't be an error to have `alignof==16` but that would mean you couldn't use glibc's `malloc`. Then again, the Standard restricts the implementation's `malloc`, not the OS'es `malloc`. GCC might need to wrap glibc. (Which I think should be done anyway)

Comment: `alignof` returns `64`. `alignof(max_align_t)` returns `8` (expected). There is no user requirement on alignment on either the object or its members; why would `alignof` be `64` ? I am not using `malloc` directly but assumed that `new` was using it.

Comment: Well well well... A few levels deep within the struct, I just found a required alignment to cache line size. This is the reason for `alignof==64` on the whole thing. And it also means, as both @TrentP and @MSalters pointed out, that I cannot use 8-byte aligned `new`. Used to work by chance with previous versions and lesser optimizations because GCC was not taking advantage of the overall alignment...

Comment: (Feel free to make your comments answers for me to validate)

Comment: It's a pretty well known problem that GCC's vectorizer occasionally screws up alignment. Though I wasn't aware it was still a problem as of 6.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the compiler has a reason to think the object has an alignment ≥ 16 bytes.  It's possible to find out what the compiler thinks the alignment is by using the `alignof()` operator in C++11.  GCC has an extension `__alignof__` that is available in C and earlier C++ versions.

A structure's alignment is the highest alignment of anything in it, recursively.  There could be something in there with higher alignment than expected.

While the C++11 standard guarantees that memory returned by `new` is aligned to the value needed by the "fundamental alignment requirement" of any object, this only applies to standard types and objects made of them.  Using C++11 `alignas()` or the `__attribute__((aligned(x)))` GCC extension to request higher alignment might exceed what `new` provides.

A solution to this would be to use `std::aligned_alloc()` (C++11 or later) or `posix_memalign()` (POSIX-only but < C++11) to get aligned memory.  This could be coupled with the placement form of the `new` operator to construct the object in that memory or class specific operator overloads of `new` and `delete`.

Comment: I also want to point out that in the c++17 standard, dynamic allocation will be made to honor even over-aligned data. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r1.html